# With pandas, How to generate bins from midpoints?

Tags: python, pandas, intervals

For example : i have midpoints of intervals :

```
midpoints=[1,2,4]
```

and want to convert that to intervals :

```
 intervals=[0.,1.5,3.,+infinity]
```

is that possible ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is just the rolling average:

```
ser = pd.Series([1,2,4]).rolling(window=2,center=False).mean()
```

Then maybe some handling for top and bottom values:

```
ser_end = pd.Series([np.inf])
output_ser = ser.append(ser_end).fillna(0)
```

Worth noting that depending on usecase it might be more valid to fill the missing value at the start with -infinity